# Pandas fillna on a multiindex series

Tags: python, pandas

The `series_A` with NAs is indexed by a MultiIndex `(X, Y)`, while the values to fill in are in the `Series_B`, which is indexed by `X`. How to effectively approach this kind of problem?

For example, here is the `series_A`:

```
bar  one    0.299368
     two         NaN
baz  one   -0.863838
     two   -0.251905
foo  one    1.063327
     two         NaN
qux  one    0.206053
     two    0.408204
```

and `series_B` contains values to fill in:

```
bar  0.123
foo  0.456
```

Comment: Question needs improvement

Comment: Just updated the post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Method 1**
*use `unstack` to put first level of index into columns and then use `fillna`*

```
series_A.unstack(0).fillna(series_B).unstack().dropna()

bar  one    0.299368
     two    0.123000
baz  one   -0.863838
     two   -0.251905
foo  one    1.063327
     two    0.456000
qux  one    0.206053
quz  two    0.408204
dtype: float64
```

**Method 2**
*use `add` method to leverage its `level` and `fill_value` parameters then `combine_first`*

```
series_A.combine_first(series_A.add(series_B, level=0, fill_value=0))

bar  one    0.299368
     two    0.123000
baz  one   -0.863838
     two   -0.251905
foo  one    1.063327
     two    0.456000
qux  one    0.206053
quz  two    0.408204
dtype: float64
```

**Method 3**
*use `map` on the `Index` object returned from `series_A.index.get_level_vaues(0)` with the callable `series_B.get`*

```
series_A.fillna(
    pd.Series(series_A.index.get_level_values(0).map(series_B.get), series_A.index)
)

bar  one    0.299368
     two    0.123000
baz  one   -0.863838
     two   -0.251905
foo  one    1.063327
     two    0.456000
qux  one    0.206053
quz  two    0.408204
dtype: float64
```

**Method 4**
*use `np.isnan` and `np.flatnonzero` to find the positions of where the `np.nan`s are.  Then find the values to insert with `get_level_values` and `map`.  Finally, place into location with `iloc`*

```
i = np.flatnonzero(np.isnan(series_A.values))
series_A.iloc[i] = series_A.index.get_level_values(0)[i].map(series_B.get)
series_A

bar  one    0.299368
     two    0.123000
baz  one   -0.863838
     two   -0.251905
foo  one    1.063327
     two    0.456000
qux  one    0.206053
quz  two    0.408204
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been really expert at helping me overcome so many of my frustrations :D

Comment: @JamesWong glad I could help!